# How create a subquery with eloquent and laravel with softdeletes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 7 and Vue.js 2.
I want to retrieve the tasks that are not assigned to a specific user.

I made the following code that works correctly.

```
    $tasks_user = TaskUser::select('task_id')
        ->where('user_id', $id)
        ->get();

    $tasks = Task::select('tasks.id as id', 'tasks.name as name', 'tasks.description as description')
        ->join('task_user', 'tasks.id', '=', 'task_user.task_id')
        ->whereNotIn('task_user.task_id', $tasks_user)
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

By the way to be more elegant I decided to transform the above code into a single query as follows:

```
    $tasks = Task::select('tasks.id as id', 'tasks.name as name', 'tasks.description as description')
        ->join('task_user', 'tasks.id', '=', 'task_user.task_id')
        ->whereNotIn('task_user.task_id', function($q) use ($id)
        {
            $q->select('task_id')
            ->from('task_user')
            ->where('user_id', $id)
            ->get();
        })
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

Unfortunately I discovered that the above query didn't work because it doesn't considers softdeletes.
For example, if the user with `id` 3 was related with the task `7` but now that row has been deleted with softdeletes in the table `task_user`, the first code returns also the task with `id` 7 (correctly) and the second one not (uncorrectly).
So finally, I must do a single query that works as the first code.
Can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually combine both approaches. whereNotIn accepts also an Eloquent Query, it doesnt need to be a callback. Try this:

```
$userRelatedTasksQuery = TaskUser::select('task_id')
    ->where('user_id', $id);

$tasks = Task::select('tasks.id as id', 'tasks.name as name', 'tasks.description as description')
    ->join('task_user', 'tasks.id', '=', 'task_user.task_id')
    ->whereNotIn('task_user.task_id', $userRelatedTasksQuery)
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Be sure to not use get() at the end of the $userReleatedTasksQuery, as you want the eloquent query instance, not the result.